# SOmething strange with Spring MVC and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Strange error marked by Eclipse
Here is code

```
@RequestMapping ("/hello")
public ModelAndView showMessage(@PathVariable(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {

}
```

So required and defaultValue marked with error

> The attribute required is undefined for the annotation type PathVariable

EM ??

Spring version is 4.3.0.RELEASE
Here is my imports:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

Yes. When I use RequestParam - all is ok. But my snippet

```
@RequestMapping ("/hello")
public ModelAndView showMessage(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
    model.addObject("name", name);

    return model;
}
```

prints string with ${name} - not with the value of name - this is linked somehow?
this reference work it

```
<a href="hello?name=Eric">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: what is the version of spring are you using?

Comment: Please post helloworld view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is the only attribute defined in annotation `PathVariable` Spring provides

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
```

So you are getting error on `required` and `defaultValue`

If you are using any other `JAX-RS` which supports `PathVariable` annotation with `required` and `defaultValue` then change the import statement to the correct one.

**EDIT**

`RequestParam` has `required` and `defaultValue`, I think you need to use `RequestParam` instead of `PathVariable` to have default value

Comment: And why this damned Tomcat can't get my updated index.jsp ??!! - other pages is ok

Comment: Please don't add questions in the existing post, please create a new question and post